# How to insert html for angular?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, firebase

I have a script that listens for online presence and I would like to use angular for the html that I insert, but the `openChatWindow()` call is not working.

```
 $("#i"+getMessageId(snapshot)).append('<img id="theImg" class="ui avatar image" ng-click="openChatWindow()" style="float:left;" src="'+chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")+'" />')
```

The ng directives work on other parts of the page. Why does the `ng-click` fail?

My script (that reside in `app/scripts`)

```
var name = prompt("Your name?", "Guest");
  var currentStatus = "online";

  // Get a reference to the presence data in Firebase.
  var userListRef = new Firebase("https://sizzling-inferno-2758.firebaseio.com/");

  // Generate a reference to a new location for my user with push.
  var myUserRef = userListRef.push();

  // Get a reference to my own presence status.
  var connectedRef = new Firebase("https://sizzling-inferno-2758.firebaseio.com//.info/connected");

  connectedRef.on("value", function(isOnline) {
    if (isOnline.val()) {
      // If we lose our internet connection, we want ourselves removed from the list.
      myUserRef.onDisconnect().remove();

      // Set our initial online status.
      setUserStatus("online");
    }
    else {

      // We need to catch anytime we are marked as offline and then set the correct status. We
      // could be marked as offline 1) on page load or 2) when we lose our internet connection
      // temporarily.
      setUserStatus(currentStatus);
    }
  });

  // A helper function to let us set our own state.
  function setUserStatus(status) {
    // Set our status in the list of online users.
    currentStatus = status;
    myUserRef.set({ name: name, status: status });
  }

  function getMessageId(snapshot) {
    return snapshot.key().replace(/[^a-z0-9\-\_]/gi,'');
  }

  // Update our GUI to show someone"s online status.
  userListRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var user = snapshot.val();
if (user.name!=undefined) {

   $("<div/>")
      .attr("class","greendot")
      .attr("style","float:left")
      .appendTo("#presenceDiv");

   //  $("<img/")
     // .attr("class","ui avatar image")
      //.attr("style","float:left")
       //.attr("ng-hide","showHide")
       // .attr("ng-src","{{user.image}}")
      //.appendTo("#presenceDiv");
  $('#presenceDiv').append('<img id="theImg" class="ui avatar image" style="float:left;" src="'+chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")+'" />')
    $("<div/>")
      .attr("id", getMessageId(snapshot))
       .attr("style","color:white")
      .text(user.name + " is currently " + user.status)
      .appendTo("#presenceDiv");


  } 
  });

  // Update our GUI to remove the status of a user who has left.
  userListRef.on("child_removed", function(snapshot) {
    $("#presenceDiv").children("#" + getMessageId(snapshot))
      .remove();
  });

  // Update our GUI to change a user"s status.
  userListRef.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
    var user = snapshot.val();
    $("#presenceDiv").children("#" + getMessageId(snapshot))
      .text(user.name + " is currently " + user.status);
  });

  // Use idle/away/back events created by idle.js to update our status information.
  document.onIdle = function () {
    setUserStatus("idle");
  }
  document.onAway = function () {
    setUserStatus("away");
  }
  document.onBack = function (isIdle, isAway) {
    setUserStatus("online");
  }

  setIdleTimeout(5000);
  setAwayTimeout(10000);
```

My controller

```
myApp.controller("SidebarController", function ($scope) {

    var content = [
        { title: 'Andorra' },
        { title: 'United Arab Emirates' },
        { title: 'Afghanistan' },
        { title: 'Antigua' },
        { title: 'Anguilla' },
        { title: 'Albania' },
        { title: 'Armenia' },
        { title: 'Netherlands Antilles' },
        { title: 'Angola' },
        { title: 'Argentina' },
        { title: 'American Samoa' },
        { title: 'Austria' },
        { title: 'Australia' },
        { title: 'Aruba' },
        { title: 'Aland Islands' },
        { title: 'Azerbaijan' },
        { title: 'Bosnia' },
        { title: 'Barbados' },
        { title: 'Bangladesh' },
        { title: 'Belgium' },
        { title: 'Burkina Faso' },
        { title: 'Bulgaria' },
        { title: 'Bahrain' },
        { title: 'Burundi' }
        // etc
    ];

    $scope.users = [
        {name: "Olle", image: chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")},
        {name: "Llle", image: chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")},
        {name: "Slle", image: chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")},
        {name: "Kalle", image: chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")}
    ];

    $('.ui.search').search({ source: content});

    $scope.value = "Text";


    $scope.addFriendClick = function() {
        //var popupScope = angular.element($("[ng-controller='PopupDialogController']")).scope();
        //popupScope.show();
        console.log("Clicked");
        alert("hello");
    }
    $scope.openChatWindow = function () {;
        console.log("Clicked open chat");
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ greeting: "channels" }, function (response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
        });
    }
    $scope.openChannels = function () {;
        console.log("Clicked open channels");

        $scope.users = [
            {name: "Kanal1"},
            {name: "Kanal2"},
            {name: "Kanal3"},
            {name: "Kanal4"}
        ];
        $scope.showHide = true;
        $scope.$apply();

    }
    $scope.openUsers = function () {;
        console.log("Clicked open users");

        $scope.users = [
            {name: "Olle", image: chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")},
            {name: "Llle", image: chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")},
            {name: "Slle", image: chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")},
            {name: "Kalle", image: chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")}
        ];
        $scope.showHide = false;

        $scope.$apply();

    }
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $("#profile").attr("src", chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png"));
        setTimeout(function(){

        }, 0);
    });
});
```

My app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('AngularChromeEx', ["firebase"], function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|chrome-extension):|data:image\//);
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|chrome-extension):/);
});
/*
myApp.factory('Server', ['$http', function ($http) {
  return {
    get: function(url) {
      return $http.get(url);
    },
    post: function(url) {
      return $http.post(url);
    },
  };
}]);
*/

myApp.controller('SidebarController', function($scope) {

  $scope.showHide = false;

});

myApp.controller("SidebarController", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://sizzling-inferno-2758.firebaseio.com/messages");
  // create a synchronized array
  // click on `index.html` above to see it used in the DOM!
  $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);
});
```

My manifest.js

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "scripts/chromereload.js",
      "scripts/jsclasses/Injection.js",
      "scripts/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon-19.png",
      "38": "images/icon-38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "angular injection",
   "default_popup": "browser_action/browser_action.html"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "styles/reset.css",
        "bower_components/angular/angular-csp.css",
        "bower_components/semantic/dist/semantic.css",
        "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery-ui.min.css",
        "styles/main.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
        "bower_components/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js",
        "bower_components/angular/angular.min.js",
        "scripts/app.js",
        "scripts/controllers/PopupDialogController.js",
        "scripts/controllers/SidebarController.js",
        "scripts/contentscript.js",
        "scripts/firebase.js",
        "bower_components/angularfire/index.js",
           "bower_components/angular/index.js"

      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ],
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js https://*.firebaseio.com https://*.firebaseio-demo.com; object-src 'self'",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "bower_components/angular/*",
    "bower_components/semantic/*",
    "images/*",
    "bower_components/semantic/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts/*",
    "bower_components/semantic/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff",
    "scripts/views/*"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

My view

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="SidePanelModule" ng-csp="">
<head>
  <link href="../../styles/sidepanelmodule.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../../bower_components/angular/angular-csp.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../../bower_components/semantic/dist/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../bower_components/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../sidepanelapp.js"></script>
  <script src="../controllers/SidebarController.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/idle.js"></script>
        <script src="../../scripts/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav ng-controller="SidebarController" class="rightSlider">
<div class="siderbar-inner">
  <div class="ui aligned padded grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="five wide column">
        <img width="50px" height="50px" id="profile" class="ui circular image">
      </div>
      <div class="five wide column">
        <h3 style="margin-top: 15px;">Patrick</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="centered row">
      <div style="width: 200px; height: 30px;" class="ui icon input">
        <input id="search" class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search animals...">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="ui clearing divider"></div> 
        <div ng-show="showHide" ng-hide="!showHide" style="color:white;">
          <b>Your recent discussions</b>
        </div>

         <div id="presenceDiv" class="l-demo-container example-base">
</div>
    <script src="../../scripts/presence.js"></script>
        <!--
        <div class="ui middle aligned selection list" ng-repeat="user in users">
          <div class="item">
            <div ng-hide="showHide" ng-show="!showHide" class="greendot"></div>
            <i ng-show="showHide" ng-hide="!showHide" class="remove circle outline icon large" style="float:left;color:white;"></i>
            <img ng-hide="showHide" ng-src="{{user.image}}" class="ui avatar image">
            <div class="content">
              <a ng-click="openChatWindow()" class="header, reader">{{user.name}}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="centered row">
      <div class="ui clearing divider"></div>
      <button ng-click="addFriendClick()" class="ui primary button">
        Add friends {{value}}
      </button>
    </div>



    <div class="centered row">
        <div class="four ui buttons">
          <div class="ui icon button home" data-content="Home">
            <i class="home icon"></i>
          </div>
          <button class="mini ui button"><i class="tags icon"></i></button>
          <button ng-click="openChannels()" class="mini ui button"><i class="history icon"></i></button>
          <button  ng-click="openUsers()" class="mini ui button"><i class="users icon"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: must use `$compile` for angular to recognize directives/expressions you insert in dom. Most likely if you got rid of using jQuery for this and used data model to drive view you wouldn't have any issues

Comment: @charlietfl Can you please show me how I use it? I never did that before.

Comment: perhaps, but why are you using jQuery to insert html in the first place? Also have no idea where you are using this code

Comment: @charlietfl I took the code from an example (online presence sytem) that not uses angular. so I'm not sure if angular is known in the file. I'm developing a google chrome plugin in this script is included where angular is used for the view and controller. the code is not in the controller but in a parallel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

**EDIT :**

Well,

After looking at your code, I think you want append the new element using a function positioned in a non-angular component. And I'm sure you are not using the classic way for $compile, a directive.

If you want add an element to the DOM with a directive as attribute, outside of a directive, you have to do :

```
$(function() {
    var img = '<img id="theImg" class="ui avatar image" ng-click="openChatWindow()" style="float:left;" src="'+chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")+'" />';
    angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        $("#i"+getMessageId(snapshot)).append($compile(img)($rootScope));
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });
});
```

This should work and update the invoked existing scope (know new elements).

If injector is undefined, create your own like that :

```
$(function() {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    var img = '<img id="theImg" class="ui avatar image" ng-click="openChatWindow()" style="float:left;" src="'+chrome.extension.getURL("images/patrick.png")+'" />';
    $injector.invoke(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        $("#i"+getMessageId(snapshot)).append($compile(img)($rootScope));
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });
});
```

This will work

Comment: `angular.element()` does not use `$compile`. This will do no different than using jQuery

Comment: still missing the scope argument and if OP is loading jQuery in extension only (after angular loads in page) `angular.element` won't work with ID selector

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now we're getting somewhere. But I'm getting the error msg `Uncaught ReferenceError: $compile is not defined` in the console.

Comment: @Programmer400 it won't be because it needs to be injected into an angular component

Comment: @charlietfl Can you please show e how I inject it or must I move my code to the contoller? The script is like a realtime listener for online presence and Im not sure that the controller can do that.

Comment: @Programmer400 please insert your code in a gist or fiddle and edit your answer with it, we will help you

Comment: @chalas_r I added my scripts and views to the question. I'm thinking about doing it with angularfire since it is a firebase project with angular and a google chrome extension.

Comment: @Programmer400 Thank's for sharing your code. But the line of code you given before add your code is not present in your files.
In which file (and function ?) you want append the element with ng-click directive as attribute ? In your script (first) or in an angular component (like your controller) ?

Comment: @chalas_r Thank you for the help. The code where I want to append the element is in my first script, it is instead of appending to the `presenceDiv` that I instead want to use angular and append the element with ng-click directive.

Comment: Ok, look at my answer,  I have made edits.  Take the last code block and try it in your script

Comment: @chalas_r Thank you but it didn't work. It did render the image but it was not clickable. I feel frustrated because I'm not even trying to achieve something difficult. All I want is to create a link and then suddenly nothing is possible no matter how hard we try.

Comment: Do you have any error in browser console ? I've tried this two exemples directly in markup and it works for me. I Will EDIT my answer and integrate the exemple in your code